# Condição e loop dentro de uma função

Tags: sql, postgresql, pl-sql

Estou criando uma função para dar saída do estoque, onde `v_saldo_item_peps` é uma função que retorna uma tabela, com os item que possuem saldo, em suas respectivas entradas.

Preciso verificar se `v_saldo_item_peps` retornou algum resultado e percorrer essas linhas dando as saídas, enquanto não tiver alcançado o total e houver saldo em estoque na coluna `saldo_atual_individual`.

Ps. O código atual funciona, porém se a Qtd informada nos parâmetros for maior que a quantidade disponível, fica com valor negativo, e se não houver nenhuma linha retornada pela função, os campos de QtdAtual e valores ficam nulos. O  que não pode acontecer.

Coloquei no SQLFiddle para ajudar:
[http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/87a17/2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/87a17/1)

Código da função:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.saida_estoque (  produto varchar,  estoque 

varchar,  lote varchar, qtd numeric)
RETURNS INTEGER  AS
$body$
with xAtual as (
SELECT
 codigo,
 custo_medio,
 data,
 estoque,
 lote,
 produto,
 qtd,
 valor,
 saldo_atual,
 saldo_atual_individual
FROM
v_saldo_item_peps($1,$2,$3))

--Aqui verificar se xAtual tem registros, caso contrário cancelar tudo.
--Percorrer cada linha, executando as saídas (`INSERTS`).
--Ex. qtd = 10, na primeira linha saldo_atual_individual = 5. 
--Dá saída em 5 unidades, pela primeira linha, vai para a próxima.
--Na segunda linha, saldo_atual_individual  = 6.
--Dá saída em 5, e fica 1 de saldo naquela entrada.
--Se possível, ao final, retornar um INTEGER[] com todos os códigos gerados nas sáidas `(INSERT)`.
--Se chegar na última linha e ainda não tiver saldo para completar, cancelar tudo.


INSERT INTO 
  public.estoque
(
  produto,
  lote,
  estoque,
  data,
  qtd,
  valor,
  saldo_anterior,
  saldo_atual,
  custo_medio,
  id_peps,
  saldo_ant_peps,
  saldo_atual_peps
) 
VALUES (
  $1,
  $3,
  $2,
  now(),
  $4,
  (SELECT x.valor from xAtual x),--valor saida
  (COALESCE((SELECT x.saldo_atual from estoque x where x.produto = $1 and x.lote = $3 and x.estoque = $2 order by x.codigo desc limit 1),0)),
  (coalesce((SELECT x.saldo_atual from estoque x where x.produto = $1 and x.lote = $3 and x.estoque = $2 order by x.codigo desc limit 1),0) + $4),
  (SELECT x.custo_medio from xAtual x),--preco medio
  (SELECT x.codigo from xAtual x)  ,--Codigo da entrada q deu saída
  (SELECT x.saldo_atual_individual from xAtual x),--saldo anterior
  (SELECT x.saldo_atual_individual from xAtual x) + $4 --Saldo Atual
) returning codigo;



$body$
LANGUAGE 'sql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;
```

Obs: Estou apenas fazendo testes, não é meu código final, desconsiderar nomenclatura / ordem e tipo dos parâmetros / etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolvido:**

Meu problema era saber a sintaxe para a função.

A `language` estava definida para `sql`, sendo assim não suportaria condicionais e loop. Tive que alterar para `plpgsql`, e esta não suportava as tabelas temporárias. Então foi definido um `cursor` para armazenar o resultado da função `v_saldo_item_peps`.

Alterei o tipo de retorno para `integer[]` para retornar todas as chaves dos registros inseridos durante o processo, e declarei algumas variáveis para calcular os saldos disponíveis / quantidade de movimentos.

Finalmente ficou assim minha função:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.saida_estoque (  produto varchar,  estoque varchar,  lote varchar, qtd numeric)
RETURNS INTEGER[]  AS
$body$
declare 

retorno integer[] DEFAULT '{}';
xaux integer; --variavel auxiliar resultado do insert
temptable CURSOR FOR Select * from v_saldo_item_peps($1,$2,$3); --tabela (cursor) temporaria entradas / estoque / saldo atual
qtdMov numeric; --variavel com a qtd de cada movimento inserido
qtdRestante numeric; --qtd restante a inserir nos movimentos
diferenca numeric; --qtd da diferenca entre saldo atual e movimento

BEGIN

qtdMov := $4;
qtdRestante := qtdMov;

FOR xAtual in  temptable LOOP

--xAtual.saldo_atual_individual --Saldo atual do item / entrada

diferenca := xAtual.saldo_atual_individual + qtdRestante;
IF (diferenca <0) then
qtdMov := qtdRestante - diferenca;
else
qtdMov := qtdRestante;
end if;

qtdRestante := qtdRestante - qtdMov;


INSERT INTO 
  public.estoque
(
  produto,
  lote,
  estoque,
  data,
  qtd,
  valor,
  saldo_anterior,
  saldo_atual,
  custo_medio,
  id_peps,
  saldo_ant_peps,
  saldo_atual_peps
) 
VALUES (
  $1,
  $3,
  $2,
  now(),
  qtdMov,
  (xAtual.valor),--valor saida
  (COALESCE((SELECT x.saldo_atual from estoque x where x.produto = $1 and x.lote = $3 and x.estoque = $2 order by x.codigo desc limit 1),0)),
  (coalesce((SELECT x.saldo_atual from estoque x where x.produto = $1 and x.lote = $3 and x.estoque = $2 order by x.codigo desc limit 1),0) + qtdMov),
  (xAtual.custo_medio),--preco medio
  (xAtual.codigo)  ,--ref
  (xAtual.saldo_atual_individual),--saldo anterior
  (xAtual.saldo_atual_individual) + qtdMov
) returning codigo into xaux;

  retorno := retorno || xaux ;

  if (qtdRestante = 0) THEN
     EXIT;
  END IF;


END LOOP;

if (qtdRestante != 0) then
     RAISE EXCEPTION 'Não há saldo do item.'; 
end if;

return retorno;

END;


$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;
```

Apesar de não ter tido respostas, deixo aqui minha solução para a questão para que possa ser útil a alguém futuramente.